# How to set changed menu icon permanently when app restarted

Tags: android

I have Already changed menu item dynamically but when app get restarted it changes back to default icon.How can i changed that icon permanently?

case R.id.action_bookmark:

```
                                                           String isBookmark=data.getBookmark();
                                                           if(isBookmark.equals("false")) {
                                                               NewsModel newsModel=items.get(getAdapterPosition());
                                                               newsModel.setBookmark("true");
                                                               ContentValues values = newsModel.getContentValues();
                                                               NewsTable.getInstance().updateEntry(newsModel.getId(),values);
                                                               item.setIcon(R.drawable.star);
                                                               notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                           }
                                                           else{
                                                               NewsModel newsModel=items.get(getAdapterPosition());
                                                               newsModel.setBookmark("false");
                                                               ContentValues values = newsModel.getContentValues();
                                                               NewsTable.getInstance().updateEntry(newsModel.getId(),values);
                                                               item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_white_24dp);
                                                               notifyDataSetChanged();

                                                           }
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. I suggest you to add more information in form of coding and show steps you have taken to solve problem.

Comment: Pls elaborate the "Restarted" part.

Comment: When the app open again.

Comment: I m able to change icon dynamically using notifydatasetchanged().But this is not permanent when app open again

Answer (score 0):

Save state of that item using `SharedPreferences` in `onPause()`. Then, every `onResume()` read the value from `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("program", MODE_PRIVATE);

if (sp.getString("key", "null").equals("item1")) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    setOptionIcon(menu.findItem(R.id.action_1),R.drawable.one);
}else{
setOptionIcon(menu.findItem(R.id.action_2),R.drawable.two);
}
```